# MongoDB connection method

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am working on an application and am still trying to get the full grasp of Node.JS

I have a file (mongodb.js) with my method to connect to my database. But my server file is separate. How do I configure my server to automatically run the connect method even though its in a separate file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different way to implement that, this is just one of them.

Exporting your connect function so that it call be called from your main server file like this.

This should go on your **mongodb.js** file

```
//mongodb.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose'); //if you are using mongoose of course
const {MONGO_URI} = require('./keys'); //Your db settings and credentials

module.exports = mongoose.connect(MONGO_URI, { // this is the important part, module.exports
 useNewUrlParser:true,
 useUnifiedTopology:true
})
mongoose.connection.on('connected',()=>{
 console.log('connected to mongo');
})
mongoose.connection.on('error',(err)=>{
 console.log('error connecting to mongo', err);
})
```

And this on your **main server** file

```
//server.js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const dbconnection = require('./mongodb') //require your mongo connection funtion
const PORT  = 5000

app.listen(PORT, ()=>{
 console.log(`server running on ${PORT}`);
})
```

Comment: Glad it worked for you, remember to accept the answer if the issue is solved